# Scheme full-house poke function

Tags: list, scheme, lisp, racket

I'm trying to define a function in Scheme that determines if a five-element list contains a full-house (that is, 3 elements are the same and the other 2 are the same, respectively). I have the outline in my head, although I'm messing up the syntax. I'm using and, let, to try and do this. The input is a list (5 elements, number 1-13) and the output is a Boolean. Here is what I have so far:

```
(define is-full-house?
  (lambda (listy)
    ;; Sort listy from smallest to greatest
    (let ((sorted-list (sort listy <=)))
        (and 
         ((= (first sorted-list) (second sorted-list)) (= (fourth sorted-list) (fifth sorted-list))))
        (or
         ((= third fourth)) (= first third)))))
```

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were close - but make sure you understand what *is* a full-house in the first place, and the correct way to use the boolean connectors in this case. Try this:

```
(define is-full-house?
  (lambda (listy)
    (let ((sorted-list (sort listy <=)))
      (or
       (and
        (= (first sorted-list) (second sorted-list) (third sorted-list))
        (= (fourth sorted-list) (fifth sorted-list)))
       (and
        (= (first sorted-list) (second sorted-list))
        (= (third sorted-list) (fourth sorted-list) (fifth sorted-list)))))))
```